# Angular 2 - Can't run the correct function when button is placed inside a selectable anchor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an anchor which is selectble and assigned a `(click)` listener to it.  Inside this anchor is a button (used for an editing popup module) with its own `(click)` listener.

Example:

```
<a (click)="onClick(myId)" class="list-group-item clearfix">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{name}}</h4>
  </div>
  <div style="float: right">
    <button type="button" (click)="onEdit(myId)" pButton class="ui-button-myButton" icon="fa-pencil"></button>
  </div>​
</a>
```

[image]

I can't manage to call `(click)="onEdit(myId)"` only when it's clicked without triggering the first function `(click)="onClick(myId)"` as both functions a called.

I've tried naming both functions the same name and passing a boolean (e.g. run first function if `true` or second if `false`) but both events occur.

I've also tried assigning the first `onClick(myId)` to the first div but this only triggers the listener when the text is selected (rather than the entire anchor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because **events bubbling**. You need to pass the `$event` object into the function and call `event.stopPropagation()`;

```
<div style="float: right">
   <button type="button" (click)="onEdit($event, myId)" pButton class="ui-button-myButton" icon="fa-pencil"></button>
</div>​
```

and in the function call

```
onEdit(event, myId) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   // then your logic
}
```

Your function will take two parameters, the first is the `event` object and the second is your `id`.

**Event Bubbling**

When an `event` is triggered on the `element3`, the same `event` is also triggered for the `element2` and `element1`. You can stop this execution using `stopPropagation()`  function.

```
---------------| |-----------------
| element1     | |                |
|   -----------| |-----------     |
|   |element2  | |          |     |
|   -------------------------     |
|        element3                 |
-----------------------------------
```